# Windows 7 saving Office files to DFS fileserver has significant delay

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

There are several moving parts to this. A small section of the company who are connected from a standard floor switch to a wifi bridge to a building across the street are seeing really high save times in things like excel and word only.

The ping/response time of a computer in that building to one in ours is always less than 1ms.  Internet traffic and everything else seems to be fine. It only seems to be related to saving.

We are running Windows 2008 fileservers with DFS, only taking advantage of namespace, so only one file server at the moment.

I've run wireshark and cant seem to see anything different from a normal workstation.

Comment: Ok, you have small latency, but how is your bandwidth?  Configure some bandwidth monitoring of your wireless bridge.

Comment: its a consistent 20 megs from what I can tell